# Module not found error even if it's imported !! PYTHON 3

Tags: python-3.x, github, module

i've been looking all day to make this python tool from github to work in order to inspect it and learn how it functions, but keep getting this **error** **even if discovery module is successfully installed** :

[image: ERROR]

Here you'll find all github's **code** : https://github.com/alanchavez88/theHarvester

**Script name** : theHarvester.py

PS : I'm using python 3

Comment: What do you mean `it's successfully installed`? How did you install it?

Comment: i installed it by : pip install discovery and also install it in pycharm

Comment: Make sure you are not installing it with `pip2` and trying to run with `python3`. That usually doesn't work too well.

Comment: I installed it with pip3 and running the script with python3 too @NoahBroyles